# Getting forbidden error while trying to make django api call from aurelia js file

Tags: django, aurelia

I have integrated aurelia js in django project, from aurelia I am trying to hit django api but CSRF issue is coming and I am not able to get results.

If I am creating normal js file in django,and calling django api from there,then its working, but incase of aurelia its not working.
My code is:

```
import {inject,DOM, autoinject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';

let httpClient = new HttpClient();
let tableHeading;

export class App {

    attached(){
        httpClient.fetch('/demographs/', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-Token": this.getCookie("csrftoken"),
                "Accept": "application/json",
                'Cache': 'no-cache',
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                'Cookie': 'csrftoken='+this.getCookie("csrftoken")
            },
            credentials: 'include'
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(data && data.table && data.table.length) {
                tableHeading = data.table[0];
            }
        });
    }

    getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = cookies[i].trim();

                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length +1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return cookieValue;
    }
}
```